# Bounty period + grace period ended. Now what?

Tags: support

I have an answer to a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/931188/how-many-ps3-ps4-controllers-can-be-hooked-up-to-one-pc-bluetooth-adapter-at-a-t/933347), and my answer has the highest votes and was made during the bounty period. About a few minutes ago, the bounty's 24-hour grace period ended, but nobody seems to have received any rep yet.

Do I have to wait *another 24 hours* for the auto-awarder to give the bounty, or should I expect the bounty to be auto-awarded within the hour?

Comment: You've received 125 rep on the post

Comment: Now I have. Hmm, that took a while.